# PHP DOMDocument: error adding DOMElement with no children

Tags: php, domdocument

```
Update: this was working and answer is in first comment

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF8');

$elRoot   = $dom->createElement ('root'); 
$elItems1 = $dom->createElement ('items1'); 
$elItems2 = $dom->createElement ('items2');
$elRoot->appendChild($elItems1); 
$elRoot->appendChild($elItems2); 
$dom->appendChild($elRoot);

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I expected this to create the following XML:

```
<root><items1></items1><items2></items2></root>
```

but instead it creates

```
<root><items1><items2></items2></items1></root>
```

If I add one children to items1 it works better but sometimes you may
have no nodes/children to you elements and then this error will occur.

Or isn't an error?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. The code is actually doing what you want. http://3v4l.org/oAKth

Comment: I added $dom->saveXML() so you run the exact same thing. I still got that error. Im running Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24. Mac OS X

Comment: @user3361120: The output is still the same as in the above demo. Are you 100% sure the above is the exact output you're getting? Please add `header('Content-Type: text/plain'; charset=utf8');` to the very top of the page to double-check.

Comment: With that setting its seems to work - thanks! Was looking in Inspector in Safari which made me confused. Guess with text/html it interprets it differently.